# c++ Check if string is valid Integer or decimal (both negative and positive cases)

Tags: c++, regex, numbers, decimal

How can I check if a string is a valid number?

```
string n1 = "0.23"; //Valid
string n2 = "123"; //Valid
string n3 = "-77"; //Valid
string n4 = "-0.73"; //Valid
string n5 = "345.567"; //Valid
string e6 = "+67"; //Invalid
string e7 = "a34"; //Invalid
string e8 = ".56"; //Invalid
string e9 = "15."; //Invalid
string e10 = "15-16"; //Invalid
string e11 = ".7-53"; //Invalid
```

I've tried this function:

```
bool is_digits(const std::string &str){
    return str.find_first_not_of("0123456789.-") == std::string::npos;
}
```

But obviously it will return `true` even if i pass as parameter the two last examples which are invalid.

```
string e8 = ".56"; //Invalid
string e9 = "15." //Invalid
```

Comment: Do you want to use Regular Expressions (you have that as one of your tags), or are you wanting to parse them on your own?  Tell us what you have tried.

Comment: This question doesn't show any effort on solving this by yourself.

Comment: why are e6, e8, and e9 invalid?  What is your desired grammar for validity?  For example, is 1.0E+6 valid?  1E6? et. al.

Comment: Because I just need to check if strings contain an Integer or a Decimal number. Is "15." a valid number?

Comment: Even if e8 and e9 were considered valid, "1.2.3" would also be valid with your is_digits implementation, but they are definitely not valid.

Comment: I know my function won't work, that's why I put it as an example, showing what i tried. If it worked my problem would be solved...

Comment: Try this regex `^[+-](?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$` It correctly finds valid integer and decimal's. It doesn't account for exponents. That's available too.

Comment: You could write your own state machine, or search the internet for an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a simple Regex:

```
bool regexmatch(string s){

    regex e ("[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)");

    if (regex_match (s,e))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

It will return true on integers (i.e. 56, -34) and floating point numbers (i.e. 6.78, -34.23, 0.6) as expected.

Comment: your regex does not seem to work on Ubuntu 15.10, g++ 5.2.1.  It also contains a "warning: unknown escape sequence: '\.'" Results probably not correct (i.e. a34 is valid?)  and couple of others.  Did I use wrong include? #include <regex>

Comment: Your regex is wrong. The `+` and `.` are special characters so you should use `\\+` and `\\.`.

Comment: Also, it matches the strings like ".9",  ".75" etc which is not the requirement